# Why can't I inject @angular/http?

Tags: typescript

Please see my AppComponent class below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  Authenticated: boolean = false;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService, private test: TestComponent) { }//, private securityService: SecurityService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('app on init');
    //this.subscription = this.securityService.authenticationChallenge$.subscribe(res => this.Authenticated = res);

    //Get configuration from server environment variables:
    console.log('configuration');
    this.configurationService.load();     
  }

  title = 'app';
}
```

and my TestComponent class below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

It works as expected i.e. Http is injected into TestComponent.  However, I want to change TestComponent to this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestComponent {

  constructor(client: Http) { }

}
```

If I attempt to inject the Http class into any class, then my Angular app compiles, however a blank white screen appears (sometimes with the word: Loading).  Why can't I inject @angular/http?

Comment: You should be injecting [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http), not `Http`. Also you generally do not inject components, you inject services / factories / etc.

Comment: Also, please don't name a *service* `TestComponent`.

Comment: @Igor, I am able to inject httpclient.  Do you know why I cant inject http out of interest?

Comment: @w0051977 Depending on your Angular version, [`http` is now deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#http).

Comment: @Nicolas, I am using visual studio 2017, which I believe is angular 8.

Comment: Visual Studio has no relationship to angular or a version of angular.

Comment: @w0051977 I'm not sure the version of VS has an impact on your angular version, but yeah, as of version 4 of angular, the `http` module has been deprecated and completely removed.

Comment: @Nicholas, according to the ng version command; I am running version 8.3.19 of the Angular CLI.

Comment: That answers your question on why you can't use `http`, that has been deprecated 4 versions ago from the version you are running. All the angular documentation and examples are based around using `HttpClient`, use that instead.

Comment: @Igor, is there a way to find ou why an angular project will not load? - there is nothing in the output window.  HttpClient works as expected, however http does not work.  Http appears to work if I create a default project from scratch in visual studio 2017.  Thanks.